# Decide if each of these rings is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

I have the following here.

> For each of the following rings $R$, decide whether it is an integral domain. If
> it is, prove so. Otherwise, explain why not with the aid of a counterexample.
> a) $R=\text{Map}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.
> b) $S=\text{Map}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})/I$, $I=\{f\in\text{Map}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})|f(1)=0\}$.

I have the following definition of an integral domain:

"An integral domain is a commutative ring $R$ such that:

i) $R$ has an identity $\mathbf{1}\neq 0$

ii) For all $a,b\in R$, if $ab=0$, then either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Additionally, an integral domain has no zero divisors."

I think a) is an integral domain. You can't multiply two non zero elements to get $0$. I am not sure how to rigorously prove this though. It just seems so obvious... For non zero elements $a$ and $b$, if I multiply $a$ and $b$, we get $ab=0$ but you can never get 0 for this ring for any two non zero elements. How do I show this rigorously though? It seems trivial.

b) Should not be an integral domain. $f(1)=0$ means that regardless of what numbers you multiply,  there will always be some kind of $0$ divisor.

I think I have the jist of this but I am not sure how to word this properly. Can someone help out here?

Comment: I would say that $0$ is always a zero divisor in a non-zero ring, therefore the only ring without zero divisors is the zero ring. For the other interpretation that $R$ shouldn't have non-zero zero divisors (which I agree with), it's already established by condition (ii).

Comment: You are claiming that $\mathbb{R}$ is an integral domain, which it is. However, the question is asking you whether the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself (with two as-yet undefined operations) is.

Comment: Isn't it an integral domain though? If I pick some random function $f(x)$ and another function $g(x)$, no matter what, multiplying both of them (If they are non zero) will never give $0$ right?

Comment: Saying $f\ne0$ means just that there _exists_ $x$ with $f(x)\ne0$, not that this holds for every $x$. So you _can_ have $f,g\ne0$, $f,g=0$ by manipulating the sets where $f$ and $g$ are non-zero

Comment: Also, I still haven't seen the definition of multiplication on this set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.**
a) $R$ is not an integral domain. (One can easily find two non-zero functions whose product is zero everywhere.)
b) $R/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. In order to show this associate to every function $f\in R$ its value at $1$, that is, $f\mapsto f(1)$ and then find the kernel and image of this map.

Comment: Don't forget to show that $f\mapsto f(1)$ is a ring homomorphism!